# Audio, DC-power and RS-485 over Ethernet, which pairs?

Tags: audio, ethernet, rs485

I'm looking for a solution to connect small Full HD cameras that normally have a very convoluted breakout-cable, over a standard Cat6A Ethernet cable. The camera's video and audio-out go over a separate HDMI connector. That won't change.
The wires I need to connect are:

- Audio in L
- Audio in R
- Audio in GND
- DC power + (6W at 12VDC (+9 – +15VDC))
- DC power -
- RS-485 TX+
- RS-485 TX-
- Joystick-control (I have no idea if this shares GND with any of the above)

The Ethernet cable I want to use is S/FTP, so all pairs are foiled and the cable itself has shielding.
The question is: how to best assign these to the four pairs to avoid as much crosstalk (audio) or noise (DC-power) as possible? Should Audio L and R go into the same pair, or better not? Should DC-power + and - go into the same pair? Does the different twist-rate of the pairs have any influence? Should I use the main shielding of the cable for any of the GND's?

Comment: Technically, it's not "Ethernet" cable as it's not for Ethernet and in fact whatever you do it will damage standars Ethernet devices. How much current and voltage for the cable?

Comment: There are a *lot* of devices which use RJ-45 connectors, and plugging in the wrong device can damage them; suggest avoiding RJ-45 connectors if possible.

Comment: How much current is on the DC power lines? You may need more than one wire in your cable for each. Even if you don't, I'm not sure the eight wires in cat 6 cable is enough to transmit this with minimal crosstalk; I'd want at least to have two wires for the audio ground, one twisted with audio L and one with audio R.

Comment: Power: 6W at 12VDC (+9 – +15VDC). Thanks for this suggestion of two wires for GND @Hearth.

Comment: @rdtsc: yes, I know, that's why I think it'd be preferable to use the PoE-standard for power.